# Any issue if a library I shipped uses AndroidX but the app using it is not?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, androidx

I have developed an Android Library which is still using old support libraries. Recently one of my  user facing multiple issues while integrating it with their App since they are using AndroidX libraries.

I am wondering whether I should migrate to AndroidX? If so, will there be any compatibility issue with the app that havn't migrated to AndroidX?

Comment: old (??) androidx or old support libraries?

Comment: old support libraries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I am wondering whether I should migrate to AndroidX?*

**Yes you should.**
All the new libraries, as [Material Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) for Android, [Firebase and Google Play services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019) require androidx migration.
Sooner or later you have to migrate.

Also [support libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library) will not be updated, it means no fixes, no new features. In the official doc you can find:

> You can continue to use the support library. Historical artifacts (those versioned 27 and earlier, and packaged as android.support.*) will remain available on Google Maven. **However, all new library development will occur in the AndroidX library.**
>
> We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX as well.

Here all info to [migrate](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

> *If so, will there be any compatibility issue with the app that havn't migrated to AndroidX*

Yes, the same issues that you are facing, but it will happen in any case with other major libraries.

Answer (score 0):

See this

> When you upload an APK, it needs to meet Google Play’s target API level requirements. Starting August 1, 2019, Google Play requires that new apps target at least Android 9.0 (API level 28), and that app updates target Android 9.0 from November 1, 2019. Until these dates, new apps and app updates must target at least Android 8.0 (API level 26).

Even if your app is in lower `targetVersion` if you're planning for an update. Then Google will push you to increase your `targetVersion` which causes you to migrate from support libraries to **AndroidX**. Also the existing libraries which will be also updated by their authors to **AndroidX**. So there's no other way, and you need to push to `androidx` components.

It's safe to migrate, and an easy process. There won't much code change if you migrate.